# Ok google speech recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Is there any open source code that would listen to OK google in real time, for further work. For example, say Ok google (or another phrase), speech recognition is activated, the google server recognizes the necessary text ---> there is a command to open the door or turn on the light, via bluetooth-arduino. I make the project helping to simplify the life of a paralyzed person. Perhaps this project will help 1000 people with disabilities.

Comment: The only project that I know it could help you is this one:
https://ifttt.com/google_assistant or this https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/device-actions-overview#custom
However, I doubt you will find something open source.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the Google Assistant in Raspberry Pi (Or other boards) and set it to open doors or whatever you need with voice commands.

Google Assistant SDK for devices:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/

Comment: Need an android application

Comment: @SergeyKuntsevich Google Assistant SDK included support for Android Things.

Codelab for it: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/androidthings-assistant/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2017#0

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/androidthings-assistant/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2017#3

Comment: Android Things development under Raspberry Pi 3. 
I can not understand why they do not use the android device + bluetooth + arduino. It's cheaper and easier.